# Symfony Console - Undefined constant STDIN

Tags: php, symfony

I recently uploaded my symfony project to my webhoster. When using the console I get the following error whenever Im supposed to enter some input.

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' in 
/htdocs/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DialogHelper.php line 80
```

The file thats giving the error is here:

https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/master/Helper/DialogHelper.php

Line 103

I asume that my php configuration is somehow wrong. However I dont have full control over the server and its settings.

Is there anything I can do to fix the issuee?

Comment: Can you access the config.php of Symfony? It shows you recommendations and errors which you need to solve to work with Symfony.

Comment: Yes, only optional recommendations are listed. Everything else is also working (Routes, Database Connection). Console Commands that dont need any additional input are also working fine

Comment: How are you calling the console script? Through your browser? Or on the command-line? In the latter case, `php` or `php-cgi`?

Comment: Im calling it on the command line by using php. I dont think php-cgi is installed and i wont have the permissions to install it

Answer (score 3):

just add :

```
define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
```

in the top of the /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DialogHelper.php

```
    <?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\Console\Helper;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyle;

define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
...
```

Comment: Changing framework files sounds like a bad idea. Can you not define STDIN inside one of your own files instead?

Comment: For similar issue, I've defined those constants in AppKarnel. Because it will be loaded for both, web and console. It worked :)

Comment: You should _never_ modify anything in the `vendor/` directory - it will be deleted on the next update, and is usually not committed into version control. Place this code in your `bin/console` and `public/index.php` files instead.